# dynamically adding a value to a statically created spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner that is created using the resource file statically. now i want to dynamically add a value to the spinner. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code looks something like step 4 in this [Hello Spinner example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) (that is, you have a programmatic reference to your Spinner using the id from your XML layout and are using an ArrayAdapter as your data source), you should be able to call [add()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#add%28T%29) on your ArrayAdapter and then call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on it as well to have your Spinner update itself.